# Spring Method Level security Getting null Property EL1007E: Property or field 'price' cannot be found on null

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

My Model Class is

```
@Data
public class Beer {
    public Beer(int i, String string, float d) {
         this.beerId = i;
         this.beerName = string;
         this.price = d;
    }
    public Beer() {
    }
    private int beerId;
    private String beerName;
    private float price;
}
```

And the Service Interface is

```
public interface IBeerService {

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @PreAuthorize("#beer.price > 0.0f")
    Beer add(Beer beer);

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")
    List<Beer> getAll();

}
```

The interface is implemented as below.

```
@Service
public class BeerService implements IBeerService {
    private List<Beer> beerRepository = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Beer add(Beer beerToAdd) {
        if(!beerRepository.contains(beerToAdd)) {
            beerToAdd.setBeerId(this.beerRepository.size()+1);
            this.beerRepository.add(beerToAdd);
        }
        return beerToAdd;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Beer> getAll() {
        return beerRepository;
    }
}
```

In the controller, I can able to see the object which is not null, in the debugger.
 I am getting an error as

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'price' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213) ~[spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Your property in the implementation is named `beerToAdd` and not `beer`.

Comment: ho yes. that the issue. then according to that, we have to keep the @Secure in implementation class?

Comment: Or keep the names the same. However it is always good to keep the annotations on the implementation rather then the contract. This is also the advice from the Spring team. It belongs on the implementation, not the contract.